# Chrome shrinking images look sharpen/glitch with background-image but normal with image tag

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, browser

I found that sometimes when images **shrink** with Css background, they looks sharpen/blurry/glitch...?

Anyway, they look weird.

Here I have two `div` with same effect but different approach, the left one use the `IMG` tag and the right one use a `DIV` with background image.

[image]

#### with img tag

```html
<div class="left">
  <img src="/image.jpg" alt="test"></img>
</div>
```

```css
.left {
  flex: 0 0 $img-w-pc;
  height: $img-w-pc * $img-ratio;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

#### with background-image

```html
<div class="right" style="background-image: url(/image.jpg)"></div>
```

```css
.right{
  flex: 0 0 $img-w-pc;
  height: $img-w-pc * $img-ratio;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The original image size is 1280 x 720 and when it's shrinking with the `background-image` it'll looks glitch.

However if I use a smaller image or enlarge the `div`, make the image "not shrink that much", then it'll be fine.

I test it on Chrome and FireFox and only the former with this problem.

What is the cause of it? Is this some special behaviors with Chrome?

**Update**

I create a codepen here: https://codepen.io/timtnlee/pen/GRjmxVK

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `image-rendering: pixelated;` declaration to the styles for your background image.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work: https://codepen.io/timtnlee/pen/GRjmxVK You can try to add `image-rendering: pixelated;` on the `.right` class.